# Comprehensive list of HTTP Status Codes THAT DON'T INCLUDE A RESPONSE BODY

Tags: http-status-codes

I was beginning to like HTTP, until I discovered that some status codes `like 304`, contain no message body and are terminated by CRLF.

Where's a comprehensive list? So far I got: `100-199`, `204`, and `304`. Are there any others?

**EDIT**: No, there are no others, according to the standard. Thanks for the answer.

I am concerned with message delimiting with persistent connections. i.e. where does one HTTP message stop and the next begin.

Comment: this is a list of HTTP status codes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)... BEWARE that even codes which return a response body might in some situations behave differently and come back with no response body (server bug, network porblem, whatever)... I would strongly recommend to not rely on the pure standard BUT to handle whatever you receive accordingly and gracefully - at least in manner that your code doesn't just die or produce incorrect results...

Comment: @Yahia what I am concerned about is ONLY HTTP Message Delimiting. i.e. Where does one message stop and the next one begin?

Comment: did you read my complete comment ?

Comment: The answer: 4.4 section of the HTTP standard, answers my question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A body is optional for all the `4xx` error codes:

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server **SHOULD** include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

Same for the `5xx`:

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server **SHOULD** include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation...

(SHOULD means that really, they should, but it's not a MUST.)

The `1xx` messages don't contain a body as far as I can tell. `201` (in addition to `204` and `205`) doesn't have to have a body. The  `3xx` are a mixed bag, but a body is optional for a lot of them.

Source: [HTTP/1.1: Status Code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

The rules for message length information are described in [HTTP Message - 4.4 Message Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4). It's not exactly trivial.

Comment: if they include no body, do they include a `Content-Length: 0` header? How do I delimit these with persistent connections?

Answer (score -1):

For RFC 9110, the current HTTP Semantics spec as of 2024-03-31, responses with the following statuses MUST NOT contain content:

### [Informational 1xx](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#name-informational-1xx)

> A 1xx response is terminated by the end of the header section; it cannot contain content or trailers.

### [204 No Content](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#name-204-no-content)

> A 204 response is terminated by the end of the header section; it cannot contain content or trailers.

### [205 Reset Content](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#name-205-reset-content)

> Since the 205 status code implies that no additional content will be provided, a server MUST NOT generate content in a 205 response.

### [304 Not Modified](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#name-304-not-modified)

> A 304 response is terminated by the end of the header section; it cannot contain content or trailers.